# How can I generate an S-curve in Excel?

Tags: excel

How can I generate a dataset that produces a notional S-Curve in Excel?

I've seen others suggest using part of a Sin or Cos function, but that doesn't look quite right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the generalized formula from Wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_function

Since I only care about the shape, I just used `=1/(1+EXP(-B1))` in cell A1, and copied that down the column. In row column B, I used values from -6 to +6

If you want specific numbers, set the values for the logistic function

`x0 = the x-value of the sigmoid's midpoint,
L = the curve's maximum value, and
k = the steepness of the curve.[1]`

in the formula `=L/(-K*(1+EXP(B1-x0)))`

In a Word document table, I used the formula `=1/(1+EXP(-[Column2]))` and hid column 2